# Can't create Organizer permission with Google Drive API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I'm creating a folder using Google Drive API and after creation I need to give an organizer permission to user. This is how I create folder:

```
$listingMainFolder = $serviceDrive->files->create(
    new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile([
        'name' => [$request->name],
        'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        'parents' => [$parentFolder]
    ])
);
```

Then I create permission:

```
$permission = $this->insertPermission($serviceDrive, $listingMainFolder->id, $listing->owner->email, 'user', 'organizer');
```

And this is the insertPermission() function:

```
function insertPermission($service, $fileId, $value, $type, $role)
{
    $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
    $newPermission->setEmailAddress($value);
    $newPermission->setType($type);
    $newPermission->setRole($role);
    $permission = $service->permissions->create($fileId, $newPermission);
    return $permission;
}
```

This gives me an error: "Organizer role is only valid for shared drives", but if I pass 'writer' instead of 'organizer' as a role, then everything works. Am I missing something when creating the folder?

P.S. I have also tried to pass transferOwnership attribute like so:

```
$permission = $service->permissions->create($fileId, $newPermission, array('fields' => 'id', 'transferOwnership' => 'true'));
```

Comment: Is the file in a shared drive? Not a shared folder, but a shared drive? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-shareddrives#specific_roles_for_shared_drives

Comment: @iansedano Seems like it's not, but how do I make a folder into shared drive via Google Drive API? Or creating a new drive is an only option?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your new question. I'm not sure you are clear on what a shared drive is, https://support.google.com/a/answer/7212025?hl=en  - to create files and folders there you can use the [create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) endpoint. You'll have to set `supportsTeamDrives` to true though. Maybe if you clarify some of the context of what you are trying to do, I can offer you a solution.

Comment: @iansedano Currently I have one folder on google drive. In this folder I create several files and I need to give users permission to edit or delete those folders and files. For now I managed to give them a writer permission, so they can edit, but they can't delete the file entirely. I need to give them permission so they could delete them as well, for that I need to make them organizers

Comment: Is the folder itself shared with those users? If you add a file or folder within an already shared folder, those permissions will be inherited. Or do you mean that this folder is NOT shared and you want to create a file inside it that another user has permission to delete?

Comment: @iansedano The folder is shared and users automatically inherit permissions when I create subfolders. As I said, they have a writer role for now and everything works as intended, but I need to make them organizers, so that they could delete these folders as well

Comment: So you want them to be able to delete and not just trash folders? Because editors/writers can trash folders if they want. They just go to the trash of the original creator.